# Expand scale with geom_blank on a facetted scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following plot:

[image: plot]

My problem is that as you can see, there is absolutely no space at all between the Y-axis and the data, same on the other side, between the data and the lateral facets.
I would like to add some space, only there.

[Edit][ But by space, I mean expanding the scale, so that my plot would basically start at an earlier date and finish at a later date. E.g. If the data starts on July 26 and finishes on December 24, I would like the plot itself to cover from July 20 to December 31. ]

I thought about using *geom_blank()* but I really can't find out how to make it work.
One thing you might need to know as well is that my x-axis is in POSIXct format.

Here is the code I used so far to obtain this plot:

```
my.breaks <- as.POSIXct(c("2015-05-01", "2015-05-10", "2015-05-15", "2015-05-20", "2015-05-25",
             "2015-06-05", "2015-06-10", "2015-06-15", "2015-06-20", "2015-06-25",
             "2015-07-05", "2015-07-10", "2015-07-15", "2015-07-20", "2015-07-25",
             "2015-08-05", "2015-08-10", "2015-08-15", "2015-08-20", "2015-08-25",
             "2015-09-05", "2015-09-10", "2015-09-15", "2015-09-20", "2015-09-25",
             "2015-10-05", "2015-10-10", "2015-10-15", "2015-10-20", "2015-10-25",
             "2015-11-05", "2015-11-10", "2015-11-15", "2015-11-20", "2015-11-25",
             "2015-12-05", "2015-12-10", "2015-12-15", "2015-12-20", "2015-12-31"))

test.dat %>%
  ggplot(aes(Date, Time2)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(Date, ymin=0, ymax=Sunrise2, group=1), fill="steelblue4", alpha = .5) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(Date, ymin=Sunset2, ymax=1, group=1), fill="steelblue4", alpha = .5) +
  geom_point(shape=20, alpha=.9) + 
  facet_grid(Mooring ~ month(test.dat$Date, label = T, abbr = F), space = "free_x", scales = "free_x", switch = "x",
             labeller=labeller(Mooring = c('M1' = 'Mooring 1', 'M2' = 'Mooring 2'))) + 
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = my.breaks, 
                   date_labels = "%e", 
                   expand = c(.02,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = c("00:00", "06:00", "12:00", "18:00", "23:59"),
                     expand = c(.02, 0)) +
  geom_blank() +
  labs(y="Time", x="") +
  theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "cm"),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = margin(.5, .5, .5, .5, "cm"),
        panel.spacing.y = unit(.3, "cm"),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(colour="grey93", size = .2),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour="grey93", size = .2),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

And here's a sample of my data to make it reproducible [Edited].

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1434758400, 1433894400, 1433635200, 
1433980800, 1439164800, 1439596800, 1441411200, 1444435200, 1435708800, 
1436227200, 1434067200, 1441584000, 1439769600, 1438214400, 1443139200, 
1441497600, 1439683200, 1436918400, 1439683200, 1436918400), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), Mooring = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("M1", 
"M10", "M11", "M12", "M2", "M3", "M4", "M5", "M6", "M7", "M8", 
"M9"), class = "factor"), Time2 = c(0.958333333333333, 0.380555555555556, 
0.447222222222222, 0.10625, 0.378472222222222, 0.717361111111111, 
0.125694444444444, 0.125694444444444, 0.413888888888889, 0.619444444444444, 
0.547222222222222, 0.653472222222222, 0.191666666666667, 0.402777777777778, 
0.344444444444444, 0.366666666666667, 0.389583333333333, 0.85625, 
0.761805555555556, 0.169444444444444), Sunrise2 = c(0.162962962962963, 
0.164363425925926, 0.165648148148148, 0.167268518518519, 0.211458333333333, 
0.218009259259259, 0.243645833333333, 0.290729166666667, 0.166493055555556, 
0.170451388888889, 0.163726851851852, 0.246319444444444, 0.218252314814815, 
0.194699074074074, 0.271921296296296, 0.246967592592593, 0.21931712962963, 
0.180613425925926, 0.21931712962963, 0.17755787037037), Sunset2 = c(0.893229166666667, 
0.889189814814815, 0.887199074074074, 0.889756944444444, 0.852395833333333, 
0.844641203703704, 0.807824074074074, 0.744618055555556, 0.892546296296296, 
0.889895833333333, 0.890335648148148, 0.804224537037037, 0.840601851851852, 
0.86744212962963, 0.773125, 0.807268518518519, 0.843055555555556, 
0.884270833333333, 0.843055555555556, 0.884097222222222)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thanks a million

Comment: Adjust your `expand = c(.02,0)`?

Comment: Hmm no, because this is also increasing the space between the facets inside the plot and I don't want that :/

Comment: OK! I see....:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post now the solution from @JonSpring!

The problem was in the following chunk of code:

```
facet_grid(Mooring ~ month(test.dat$Date, label = T, abbr = F), space = "free_x", ...
```

The mistake was "test.dat$Date". This called the dataset WITHOUT the extra rows added, which is why a conflict occurred. I believe I had added this test.dat$ previously because it used to give me an error, probably solved as well by adding `lubridate::` before calling the function `month()`

So the final code should be:

```
extra_rows <- tibble(
  Date = c(min(test.dat$Date) - lubridate::ddays(5),
           max(test.dat$Date) + lubridate::ddays(5)),
  Month = month(Date, label = T, abbr = F) %>%
    factor(levels = c("May", "June", "July", "August",
                      "September", "October", "November", 
                      "April", "December", "March")),
  Mooring = "M1"
)

test.dat %>%
  bind_rows(extra_rows) %>%  # <- add in dummy data

  ggplot(aes(Date, Time2)) + # main axes of individual plots: time vs day
  geom_ribbon(aes(Date, ymin=0, ymax=Sunrise2, group=1), fill="steelblue4", alpha = .5) + # GROUP=1 very important, or nothing will happen!
  geom_ribbon(aes(Date, ymin=Sunset2, ymax=1, group=1), fill="steelblue4", alpha = .5) +
  geom_point(shape=20, alpha=.9) + # to specify that we want points, and change settings
  facet_grid(Mooring ~ lubridate::month(Date, label = T, abbr = F), space = "free_x", scales = "free_x", switch = "x",
             labeller=labeller(Mooring = c('M1' = 'Mooring 1', 'M2' = 'Mooring 2'))) + # facet to have several panels, the first one is for the vertical panels, second horizontal
  scale_x_datetime(breaks = my.breaks, 
                   date_labels = "%e", 
                   expand = c(.02,0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = c("00:00", "06:00", "12:00", "18:00", "23:59"),
                     expand = c(.02, 0)) +
  labs(y="Time", x="") +
  theme(panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "cm"),
        strip.placement = "outside",
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        plot.margin = margin(.5, .5, .5, .5, "cm"),
        panel.spacing.y = unit(.3, "cm"),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(colour="grey93", size = .2),
        panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour="grey93", size = .2),
        panel.background = element_blank())
        #plot.background = element_blank())
```

Thanks a lot @JonSpring!

Answer (score 2):

One hack would be to add spaces into your y-axis labels and \n after your y-axis facets:

```
scale_y_continuous(labels = paste0(c("00:00", "06:00", "12:00", "18:00", "23:59"), "    "),
                     expand = c(.02, 0)) +
facet_grid(Mooring ~ month(test.dat$Date, label = T, abbr = F), space = "free_x",
           scales = "free_x", switch = "x",
           labeller=labeller(Mooring = c('M1' = 'Mooring 1\n', 'M2' = 'Mooring 2\n'))) +
```

[image]

---

Edit:
Or, we could add dummy data on either side:

```
library(lubridate)
extra_rows <- tibble(
  Date = c(min(test.dat$Date) - lubridate::ddays(5),
           max(test.dat$Date) + lubridate::ddays(5)),
  Month = month(Date, label = T, abbr = F) %>%
    factor(levels = c("May", "June", "July", "August",
                      "September", "October", "November", 
                      "April", "December", "March"))
)

test.dat %>%
  bind_rows(extra_rows) %>%  # <- add in dummy data

  ggplot(aes(Date, Time2)) + 
  # ...
```

This works well for June, but there aren't any more days in August to add to the right.

[image]

Comment: That's a good trick! But the reason why I wanted to use geom_blank() is because I would like to increase the scale, and not just only the space actually. I edited my post as I think this was not very clear in my question. That's why geom_blank() would allow me to basically add 'invisible' data to start the plot at an earlier date and finish at a later date. But I can't find a way to do it

Comment: This is challenging b/c while it's pretty straightforward to add a dummy date earlier in June, it's hard to add more space to late August when the last data is already Aug 31. What do you have in mind?

Comment: Thanks @JonSpring, seems to be the solution! But I get an error message, and tried to fix it but don't know exactly why this problem occurs. Maybe you can help?  
````Error: Tibble columns must have consistent lengths, only values of length one are recycled:
* Length 9289: Column `month(test.dat$Date, label = T, abbr = F)`
* Length 9291: Column `Mooring`
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace````  
Thanks a lot!

Comment: It sounds like `month(test.dat$Date, label = T, abbr = F)` might be NA for the two added dummy days for some reason, so you have all 9291 `Mooring` rows but only 9289 valid rows for month. Did lubridate load? Or it could I used your month factor levels from the example and those don't include all 12 months, so there could be an error if the dummy days are in Jan or Feb. Review the `extra_rows` tibble and see if you can get a valid month.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps also look at the bottom of `test.dat %>% bind_rows(extra_rows) %>% View` to make sure the two tables got combined properly.

Comment: Yes @JonSpring lubridate loaded, the tibble gives me two dates that make perfect sense, and the corresponding months as well. But it still gives me the same error. My data spans from May to December, the tibble is a 2x2. Really don't see the problem here if nothing is NA in the tibble. I actually just tried using the data sample I posted and I get the same error!

Comment: So they did got combined, with NAs everywhere (including Mooring which is also why I don't really get why in the error that column has the right number of rows), except in the Date and Month. But in the code I actually don't even use that Month column since I use month(Date) directly

Comment: I have updated in my original post the data sample that I gave you @JonSpring, because I've noticed that in what I gave you there was the wrong first column, and maybe that's why I can't replicate your code on my data... Could you try again with the updated data to see? Thanks a lot

Comment: Let's take this to chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195224/continuing-on-questions-56612813